# Sources (for beginners) to learn about R and SEM

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling

I am interested in learning how to use R and conduct experiments in it, and on getting myself familiar with Structural Equation Modeling methods. Any good advice about reliable sources (foe beginners) that I could use to this purpose?

Comment: What's your programming experience like?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any programming experience yet

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps start with the (lavaan) package in R http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/sem.html . The website's tutorial section seems to be well documented. But if you have no programming experience, you first need a little to be able to understand basic R syntax. https://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/ Seems to have an introduction at a good level.